# Learning bitwise

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why I am getting the result with my code that I am getting.

```
c = int(format(ord('c'), 'b'))
h = int(format(ord('h'), 'b'))
result = c | h

print(c)
print(h)
print(result)
```

This returns a result of:

1100011

1101000

1101035

So my question is  after the | operation, why is it 1101035 when (according to my understanding) it should be 1101011?

Comment: why are you using `int`???

Comment: Why did you edit out my other two print commands? They are there to show the binary of c and h. int is there because python was giving an error when setting result if I didn't

Comment: yeah, fixed it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `format` with the second argument being `"b"` gives you the binary representation of the number in the first argument. So, if you print it, you will see the "0"s and "1"s.

However, when you use `int` on this result, withug informing `int` that your string is base 2, it thinks these are decimal numbers. So, it will "read" the sequence "1100011" (the binary representation of 99, the unicode codepoint for the "c" character), as "1_100_011", or "one million, one hundred thousand and eleven" - and that is the number in your `c` variable if you print or make any numeric operations with it.

This can be easily solved by telling `int` that the numeric strings you are reading are binary themselves:

```
c = int(format(ord('c'), 'b'), 2)
```

(Passing 2 as the second argument to "int" to indicate the base). If you inspect "c" at this point, it contains the number 99, which will behave as expected with your "|" operator. Of course, if you are not *looking* at the binary representation of the number, there is no point in generating it to start with, so your code could be just `c = ord('c')`...

Comment: @AlchemyDragon a very important point here, `c = int(format(ord('c'), 'b'), 2)` is a convoluted way of writing `c = ord("c")`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I am looking at getting the binary for 'c' and I have to have it in int type to use with the bitwise operator '|'. Python gave an error if I kept is as a str. 'ord' does result in a int type, but format turns it to a str type.

Comment: @AlchemyDragon so what? That's exactly what `c = ord("c")` does. `format` creates a *string* not "binary". This is really fundamentally important to understand. Doing `c = int(format(ord('c'), 'b'), 2)` is a pointless, convoluted way of getting the same result as `c = ord('c')`

Answer (score 2):

Doing `int()` here makes no sense (it's taking your string of binary bits and interpreting them as a decimal number). You just want:

```
c = ord('c')
h = ord('h')
result = c | h

print(format(c, 'b'))
print(format(h, 'b'))
print(format(result, 'b'))
```

(only using `format` for display on screen, not for calculation!)

which prints:

```
1100011
1101000
1101011
```

Comment: @AlchemyDragon generally speaking, anything that smells like encoding and decoding should be done once when receiving data from the outside world, once when sending it to the outside world, and not in between. There are exceptions, but you should start there :)